Unable to install llamax-index on Python 3.13 or 3.12 under Windows 10 22H2
When I try to install llama-index using pip install llama-index I get this error:
Collecting numpy<2.0.0 (from llama-index-core<0.12.0,>=0.11.23->llama-index)
  Using cached numpy-1.26.4.tar.gz (15.8 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Installing backend dependencies ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [21 lines of output]
      + C:\Users\mellie0e\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python313\python.exe C:\Users\mellie0e\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-7uk1xcei\numpy_834b6d96156548f5a34d5a50c542aebe\vendored-meson\meson\meson.py setup C:\Users\mellie0e\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-7uk1xcei\numpy_834b6d96156548f5a34d5a50c542aebe C:\Users\mellie0e\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-7uk1xcei\numpy_834b6d96156548f5a34d5a50c542aebe\.mesonpy-lxgcjmlg -Dbuildtype=release -Db_ndebug=if-release -Db_vscrt=md --native-file=C:\Users\mellie0e\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-7uk1xcei\numpy_834b6d96156548f5a34d5a50c542aebe\.mesonpy-lxgcjmlg\meson-python-native-file.ini
      The Meson build system
      Version: 1.2.99
      Source dir: C:\Users\mellie0e\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-7uk1xcei\numpy_834b6d96156548f5a34d5a50c542aebe
      Build dir: C:\Users\mellie0e\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-7uk1xcei\numpy_834b6d96156548f5a34d5a50c542aebe\.mesonpy-lxgcjmlg
      Build type: native build
      Project name: NumPy
      Project version: 1.26.4
      WARNING: Failed to activate VS environment: Could not parse vswhere.exe output

      ..\meson.build:1:0: ERROR: Unknown compiler(s): [['icl'], ['cl'], ['cc'], ['gcc'], ['clang'], ['clang-cl'], ['pgcc']]
      The following exception(s) were encountered:
      Running `icl ""` gave "[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"
      Running `cl /?` gave "[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"
      Running `cc --version` gave "[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"
      Running `gcc --version` gave "[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"
      Running `clang --version` gave "[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"
      Running `clang-cl /?` gave "[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"
      Running `pgcc --version` gave "[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"

      A full log can be found at C:\Users\mellie0e\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-7uk1xcei\numpy_834b6d96156548f5a34d5a50c542aebe\.mesonpy-lxgcjmlg\meson-logs\meson-log.txt
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.

I tried:

removing and reinstalling Python 3.13
installing an older version: pip install llama-index==0.11.20
installing under Python 3.12

None of these fix the problem. What else can I do?

It needs a C compiler on your system, but you don't have one.

Finally I found it.
The version of llama-index I wanted to install requires numpy 1.26.4 < 2.0.0
Unfortunately, the package doesn't exist for Python 3.13 as a .whl file, only as a .gz file.
Note that the .gz format requires a C compiler on the machine, I have one with Visual Studio but there must be a problem because it can't find it.
numpy 1.26.4 exists in .whl format for Python 3.11, so install this version of Python for llama-index
